# How do I change Create Account Link in Joomla?

Tags: authentication, joomla

I just installed a Joomla 1.6 Stable release onto my webserver. However, whenever I try to create an account, it takes me down to: using-joomla/extensions/components/users-component/registration-form. How do I change the home-screen login form box to use a different page for the user-registration form?

I have looked online, and they talk about editing options in the Login Form Module, but I don't see a module called Login Form in my Modules list. Even on clean install with nothing touched.

**Note I am starting off with the sample data installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the admin backend of 1.6 you will see that under **Menus->About Joomla** the Registration link you are clicking is a sub-menu of the **Using Joomla!** menu item. So this is why that link is being dynamically created with that URL.

To create a Registration form such as **mysite.com/register** then simply create a new registration form out of that sample contents menu tree.  To do this in the admin backend go to **Menus/Your Menu/Add New Menu Item**  Then when the Menu Manager pops up to create a new menu item click the select button next to the Menu Item Type and select Users Manager->Registration Form.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sure! I can create a new "User Registration" page. However, the login form on my homepage when I am not logged in still has a link that says "Create an Account", and it is still linked to the user registration page under "About Joomla". Not the new one I created. If I delete the original registration page under "About Joomla", then I get a 404 error when I try to create an account using the link on the login form.

Comment: Did you create a new Module for your new Registration link?

Comment: Yes I tried that. Even the new Module goes to the About Joomla registration link.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I had to run to work. Anyway, it worked for me. Here's what I did. In site administration I added a new menu called Main. Then in Main I created a new menu item called Register with the Registration form type and an alias of register. Then in Module Manager I created a new Menu in the position 7 and under basic options on the top right gave it the Main menu I created.  Worked fine and it created a link to mysite.com/register

Comment: Ok I just deleted everything, reinstalled and tried it again. It worked this time. I guess I corrupted something somewhere and it was just interfering. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, so the decision was, the menu manager deleted all unnecessary. The problem is that the reference referred to the registration menu item "about joomla". PS I'm not Englishman, sorry for the spelling mistakes ...